# typescript can not found declare module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tiptap

This works

[image]

But this not

[image]

current module not import @tiptap/extension-highlight, but an external module did.

---

[apps/demo](https://github.com/wenerme/wode/tree/main/apps/demo) need type from @tiptap/extension-highlight, but this is imported by an external module at [components/tiptap/src/extensions/TipTapWordStarterKit.ts](https://github.com/wenerme/wode/blob/main/components/tiptap/src/extensions/TipTapWordStarterKit.ts), how can I make the main module (apps/demo) found the types ?

**EDIT**

Typescript not works well with pnpm & monorepo

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25376
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29808
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42873

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, `import type {} from '...'` doesn't make any sense. That import _no_ types at all.

Comment: I don't know how to express this type of error, found some related issues https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29808

Comment: @wener found a solution to your problem? I have the exact same one building an extension for tiptap!

Comment: @LéonardHenriquez work around by add type import `import type {} from '@tiptap/extension-highlight';`